# Tests breaks after I imported a single library

Tags: clojure

I'm using clojure new CLI to create a project and to run the tests I do:

```sh
clojure -M:test:runner
```

this is my test

```
(ns auth.authorize-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [auth.authorize :as auth]))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "FIXME, I fail."
    (is (= 0 0))))

;; this is working good and responding:
;; Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
```

This project will read from stdin. My first step is to get data from a file and then write it to the stdout for testing. Because of this I want import `BufferedReader` to read the file:

```
(ns auth.authorize-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [auth.authorize :as auth])

  ;; I just added this line
  (:import (java.io BufferedReader))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "FIXME, I fail."
    (is (= 0 0))))

;; This is not working and it's returning 
;; Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
```

So now is no longer doing any tests.

Comment: What was the error message?  That is very important!

Comment: @AlanThompson The reason it's what it says in the accepted answer but when I run the test I didn't get any error message. How I notice it was because the message at the end was `Ran 0 tests` instead of at least 1 tests should be ran.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most likely reason is that you have some sort of syntax error in your code.

Your code should be:

```
(ns auth.authorize-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [auth.authorize :as auth])

  ;; I just added this line
  (:import (java.io BufferedReader)))
```

Note: three closing `)` there, not two like you have in your code.

Here's what I just did:

```
(! 734)-> clojure -X:new :name auth.authorize
Generating a project called auth.authorize based on the 'lib' template.
The lib template is intended for library projects, not applications.
(! 735)-> cd auth.authorize/
(! 736)-> vi test/auth/authorize_test.clj 
# to change the test to (= 0 0)
(! 737)-> cat test/auth/authorize_test.clj 
(ns auth.authorize-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [auth.authorize :refer :all]))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "FIXME, I fail."
    (is (= 0 0))))
(! 738)-> clojure -M:test:runner

Running tests in #{"test"}

Testing auth.authorize-test

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
(! 739)-> vi test/auth/authorize_test.clj 
# add in the :import
(! 740)-> cat test/auth/authorize_test.clj 
(ns auth.authorize-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [auth.authorize :refer :all])
  (:import (java.io BufferedReader)))

(deftest a-test
  (testing "FIXME, I fail."
    (is (= 0 0))))
(! 741)-> clojure -M:test:runner

Running tests in #{"test"}

Testing auth.authorize-test

Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

And you can see that it runs the test correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Sean's answer, this is what the compiler sees:

```
(ns auth.authorize-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [auth.authorize :as auth])

  (:import (java.io BufferedReader)) ; should terminate ns form here with another `)` char

  ; Due to missing `)` above, this whole `deftest` form is inside the 'ns' form
  ; and is ignored w/o an error msg (you could consider this a compiler defect)
  (deftest a-test
           (testing "FIXME, I fail."
             (is (= 0 0))))
    
) ; end of ns form - should be after `import` keyword
```

So you see, the missing  `)` on the `:import` line is the cause of the problem.  It causes the `deftest` form to be inside of the `ns` form, which makes no sense and is a syntax error.  I'm surprised the compiler doesn't have an error for this, which I would consider a compiler bug/defect/problem, since it just silently fails instead of printing an error message of some sort.

---

### Update

Perhaps you are using an older release of Clojure? I just tried it with this config:

```
--------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.2-alpha1    Java 15
--------------------------------------
```

and I get an error:

```
Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/ns at (tst/demo/core.clj:1:1).
deftest - failed: #{:refer-clojure} at: [:ns-clauses :refer-clojure :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer-clojure
deftest - failed: #{:require} at: [:ns-clauses :require :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-require
deftest - failed: #{:import} at: [:ns-clauses :import :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-import
deftest - failed: #{:use} at: [:ns-clauses :use :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-use
deftest - failed: #{:refer} at: [:ns-clauses :refer :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer
deftest - failed: #{:load} at: [:ns-clauses :load :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-load
deftest - failed: #{:gen-class} at: [:ns-clauses :gen-class :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-gen-class

Full report at:
/tmp/clojure-8770599721946785921.edn
Tests failed.
```

and the `/tmp/clojure.....edn` file looks like:

```
{:clojure.main/message
 "Syntax error macroexpanding clojure.core/ns at (tst/demo/core.clj:1:1).\ndeftest - failed: #{:refer-clojure} at: [:ns-clauses :refer-clojure :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer-clojure\ndeftest - failed: #{:require} at: [:ns-clauses :require :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-require\ndeftest - failed: #{:import} at: [:ns-clauses :import :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-import\ndeftest - failed: #{:use} at: [:ns-clauses :use :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-use\ndeftest - failed: #{:refer} at: [:ns-clauses :refer :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer\ndeftest - failed: #{:load} at: [:ns-clauses :load :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-load\ndeftest - failed: #{:gen-class} at: [:ns-clauses :gen-class :clause] spec: :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-gen-class\n",
 :clojure.main/triage
 {:clojure.error/cause
  "Call to clojure.core/ns did not conform to spec.",
  :clojure.error/phase :macro-syntax-check,
  :clojure.error/symbol clojure.core/ns,
  :clojure.error/column 1,
  :clojure.error/line 1,
  :clojure.error/class clojure.lang.ExceptionInfo,
  :clojure.error/source "core.clj",
  :clojure.error/spec
  {:clojure.spec.alpha/problems
   ({:path [:ns-clauses :refer-clojure :clause],
     :pred #{:refer-clojure},
     :val deftest,
     :via
     [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-form
      :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer-clojure
      :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-refer-clojure],
     :in [3 0]}
    {:path [:ns-clauses :require :clause],
     :pred #{:require},
     :val deftest,
     :via
     [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-form
      :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-require
      :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-require],
     :in [3 0]}
    {:path [:ns-clauses :import :clause],
     :pred #{:import},
     :val deftest,
     :via
     [:clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-form
      :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-import
      :clojure.core.specs.alpha/ns-import],
     :in [3 0]}
     ....
```

So it appears the current version of Clojure (which uses clojure.spec to check ns forms) does detect the error in the code.